# How to get original JSON format order after updating new key value?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I updated a new JSON key value in the JSON value, but when I write the order of the JSON file is changed, so how do I get my original order with the new update key value?

Original JSON format:

```
value = [
    {
      "result": [
                        {
                              "allow": "notes",
                              "url": "https://google.com",
                              "np_url": "https://www.google.com/downloads/",
                              "rank": "2"
                              "info": "ok"
                        },
                        {
                              "allow": "notes2",
                              "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
                              "np_url": "https://imp.com/download",
                              "rank": "7",
                              "info": "cancel"
                         },
                    ]
    }
]
```

When I add new key and value the order changes when I write a JSON.

Print value shows original, but when I write and use `sort_keys = True` and without `sort_keys = True` it also gets different JSON format order

Code:

```
if
  ....
  kk['art'] = pencil
else
  ...
  kk['art'] = pencil

print(value)

import json
with open("example.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(value, f, ensure_ascii=False,indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

output:

```
value = [
    {
      "result": [
                        {
                              "allow": "notes",
                              "art": "pencil",
                              "url": "https://google.com",
                              "info": "ok"
                              "np_url": "https://www.google.com/downloads/",
                              "rank": "2"
                        },
                        {
                              "allow": "notes2",
                              "art": "pen",
                              "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
                              "info": "cancel"
                              "np_url": "https://imp.com/download",
                              "rank": "7",
                         },
                    ]
    }
]
```

expected Output:

```
value = [
    {
      "result": [
                        {
                              "allow": "notes",
                              "art": "pencil",
                              "url": "https://google.com",
                              "np_url": "https://www.google.com/downloads/",
                              "rank": "2"
                              "info": "ok"
                        },
                        {
                              "allow": "notes2",
                              "art": "pen",
                              "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
                              "np_url": "https://imp.com/download",
                              "rank": "7",
                              "info": "cancel"
                         },
                    ]
    }
]
```

Comment: If you want to preserve the order you need to stop doing `sort_keys=True`

Comment: You need to create the whole dict with the custom order of the keys you want. But you know that the order is not relevant to JSON, right?

Comment: @JonSG, in this case `art` key will be last and OP doesn't want that, nor they want sorted keys (`info` goes before `rank`)

Comment: @JonSG I tried without sort_keys = True and the order also changed

Comment: @buran yes i just updated the new key and value and the first 3 keys and value are correct after the whole order changed

Comment: create the whole dict and don't use `sort_keys=True`. I thought the last was understood.

Comment: @buran "art" is only updated and must be second order in the original json file without changing another order.but i need the original json format,I tried without sort_keys = True and the order also changed

Comment: Dictionaries maintain the order of the keys (3.7+). The order you add keys to the dictionary is the order you will see them presented. If you add a new key it will be last. If you need to specify the order of the keys in a dictionary you must do so yourself by inserting them in that order.  If you must reorder the keys (for some reason) you can create a new dictionary using `sorted()` on the `items()` where you can control the sort function.

Comment: `sort_keys=True` sorts them alphabetically. Since your desired order isn't alphabetical, why would you expect this to work?

Comment: @Angeline What version of Python are you using? I can't reproduce the output you get with Python 3.7, instead, I get the original structure's order with `"art"` appearing at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to set the order of the items in a dictionary for some reason, you must do so adding items in your chosen key order. Python preserves key insertion order as a language feature (3.7+).

I can think of a few ways that you might do this, for example creating a template dictionary with `None` values and cloning it to create individual items in your result list.

I think though I would recommend that you do whatever data manipulation you want and then iterate the result list and for each item in the list, rebuild it with an expected key ordering.

This seems straightforward enough to start.

```
value = [
    {
        "result": [
            {
                "allow": "notes",
                "art": "pencil",
                "url": "https://google.com",
                "info": "ok",
                "np_url": "https://www.google.com/downloads/",
                "rank": "2"
            },
            {
                "allow": "notes2",
                "art": "pen",
                "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
                "info": "cancel",
                "np_url": "https://imp.com/download",
                "rank": "7",
            },
        ]
    }
]

def set_key_order(my_dict):
    key_order = ["allow", "art", "url", "np_url", "rank", "info"]
    return {key: my_dict[key] for key in key_order if key in my_dict.keys()}

value[0]["result"] = [set_key_order(x) for x in value[0]["result"]]

print(value)
```

This will give you a result that looks like:

```
[
    {
        'result': [
            {
                'allow': 'notes',
                'art': 'pencil',
                'url': 'https://google.com',
                'np_url': 'https://www.google.com/downloads/',
                'rank': '2',
                'info': 'ok'
            },
            {
                'allow': 'notes2',
                'art': 'pen',
                'url': 'https://www.yahoo.com',
                'np_url': 'https://imp.com/download',
                'rank': '7',
                'info': 'cancel'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```